# Python Try Except when a list is null

Tags: python-3.x, list, try-catch, rsa, sympy

I've been searching for my problem here, but i can't find the exact answer to my problem.
I call a sympy function ( solve() ). This function can return a full list or an empty list.
I call this piece of code inside a while:

```
try:
    sol = solve([eq1,eq2],[r,s])

    rB = bin(abs(sol[0][0]))
    sB = bin(abs(sol[0][1]))
    stop = True
    r = rB[2:len(rB)]
    s = sB[2:len(sB)]
    P = int("0b"+r+s,2)
    Q = int("0b"+s+r,2)
    print(P*Q == pubKey.n)
    print("P = {}".format(P))
    print("Q = {}".format(Q))
    break
except ValueError:
    pass
```

What i want is:
if the solve() returns an empty list, just pass. And if the solve() returns a full list, keep with the execution. The solve will be returning empty list until i find the right value.
This can be reached by checking sol[0][0], if there's a non-empty list this will work, but if the list is empty, this will throw an error (null pointer) i want try to flag it and pass.

What i'm having now is that when sol is empty, it tries to get sol[0][0], and ofc this throws an error that's not being catched by the try, and the whole code stops.
Anyone knows a solution for that? I'm not using try correctly?

Comment: You could check the output of solve like `if sol == []`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set sol in the beginning of each loop to some value and check it in the except clause

**about `else`**

`try/except` has an `else` which will be run the `try` block did not raise an Exception

*and* `for` has an `else` clause for when it was not broken out of!

```py
for foo in iterable:
    # set value so the name will be available
    # can be set prior to the loop, but this clears it on each iteration
    # which seems more desirable for your case
    sol = None
    try:
        "logic here"
    except Exception:
        if isinstance(sol, list):
            "case where sol is a list and not None"
        # pass is implied
    else:  # did not raise an Exception
        break
else:  # did not break out of for loop
    raise Exception("for loop was not broken out of!")
```